# Navigate to details view controller from subviewcontroller of present view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, viewcontroller

I have `UIView` A , in view A putted View B as a subview. View B is a table view. On click of table view row it will navigate details view C. On dismiss of View C it should back to main view A.

`A>B>C`, on dismiss `A<B<C`.

But it's coming to `B<C` only.

It's on View B class-

```
  [self presentModalViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

View C

```
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It should come view A. It's not working.

Comment: As a subview or you are pushing it as viewcontroller to UINavigationController stack ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` You can use:

```
[self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

This will take you back to first ViewController of your UINavigationController stack

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using navigation controller, i'm using presentModalViewController to navigate to Details view C from View B. Its not working for me. Its navigating but at time of dismiss of view C,its return into View B , I wants to move back to View A (main view).